# Zend Frameworks - separation of content return type?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am about to develop a set of custom Ajax/rss/etc functions, both abstract, and then ones to be used in controllers. I was thinking of separating these methods based on return type.

I have a controller which will be enormous if I don't break down the logic.

I was thinking maybe a module - like

Modules/Admin/AnalyticsController
Modules/AjaxApi/AnalyticsController
Modules/RssApi/AnalyticsController

Any advice is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using or overriding or creating your own Context Switcher. You can read more here http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html

This has the features you need without needing to create new controllers for each action.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own abstract class with common methods. But in PHP you can to inherit only 1 class. Make your abstract class extends from Zend_Controller Action. Example code:

```
abstract class AjaxRssEtc extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
   // code
}
class Ajaxapi_AnalyticsController extends AjaxRssEtc
{
   // code
}
```

And your controller Ajaxapi_AnalyticsController will have methods from Zend_Controller_Action and your abstract class.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! My question is though, is this a wise design decision to separate the AJAX, from the RSS, from the XMl etc etc *as oppose* to keeping it all in one controller - AnalyticsController?